# Safe search tooltip pops up every time in Google search

Tags: google-search, cookies, google-safesearch

Every time I search using google.com, this tooltip pops up:

[image: Safe search tooltip]

It happens even if the search terms contain nothing sexual. Clicking the tooltip hides it, but it reappears on next search. I've tried to enable or disable safe search in Google settings, but it always turns back on automatically.

Removing all google.com cookies made it go away for a week, but then the tooltip reappeared.

**How can I hide this annoying popup?**

Points of note:

- I'm using Firefox 93.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04.
- I'm using following extensions, but disabling them didn't change the behavior: Google search link fix, I don't care about cookies, Quick Dictionary, Tree Style Tab.
- I'm logged into two Google accounts, one of which is part of a Google Workspace.

Tracking this down is a bit annoying, because trying an empty browser profile temporarily fixes it due to clearing cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround I found: Install ["Google (safe)"](https://mycroftproject.com/install.html?id=66996&basename=none&icontype=ico&name=Google+(safe)) custom search engine from Mycroft Project.

As can be seen from the [XML file](https://mycroftproject.com/installos.php/66996/none.xml), this adds the parameter `&safe=active` to the query. This locks the safe search setting to always on, which seems to avoid the popup tooltip.

It seems that the tooltip is somehow related to having multiple accounts logged in and having tabs open with Google applications being accessed under the different accounts. Having just one tab, the tooltip appears once if I switch the account from top right corner.